# How does JVM runtime maintain backward compatibility?

Tags: jvm, backwards-compatibility

I have a simple Java class which uses the enum reserved keyword as a variable name. I am able to compile this code in Java 1.4 and execute it in Java 1.6:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String enum = "ENUM String";
        System.out.println(enum);
    }

}
```

However the Java 1.6 compiler will not compile this code because enum is a reserved keyword. Why does Java 1.6 runtime still execute this code?

Answer (score 5):

Because when you compile your source code, it is converted into Java bytecode. So the name of your string really doesn't matter once it is compiled.

Comment: Thanks. So Java 1.6 compiler restricts enum but Java runtime doesn't care or does it know to execute this class in Java 1.4 backward compatibility mode?

Comment: The class bytecode doesn't even have names for local variables. They just get memory slot numbers.